# Having trouble reversing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, average, reverse

So I have this program that is supposed to take an array and put them in reverse order as well as give the average of said numbers. The program terminates when a negative number is entered. I am very close to finishing it but currently I am having trouble getting the reverse aspect. Help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    //Written By: Hannah Stang
    //Reads a series of positive integers until user enters -1.
    //Prints values in reverse order and gives the average of the values
    cout << "Please enter positive integers as desired, when finished enter a negative integer to get results. ";
    int sum = 0, avg, num, numsize = 0;
    cin >> num;
    void reverse (int array[] );
    while (num >= 0)
    {
        numsize = numsize + 1;
        sum = sum + num;
        cin >> num;
        avg = sum / numsize;
    }
    cout << "The values in reverse order are " << endl;
    cout << "The average is " << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: For future reference, please use a more descriptive title for your problem like "How to reverse an array of numbers".

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a homework assignment and `std::reverse(std::begin(array), std::end(array))` is out of the question?

Comment: Yes it wants me to use the void reverse function

Comment: You could search the internet for "c++ reverse array int".

Comment: BTW, what is the algorithm provided by your instructor?  What functions are you allowed to use?

Comment: I see no reversing. I see no array, even!

Comment: @HannahStang In which way would reversing the array affect the sum? Are you sure your code makes sense (besides the wrong function declaration in `main()`)?